# Conditional comparison, compare database column with parameter if parameter is greater than 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure (SQL SERVER) which accepts an @IdParameter variable (Id is non nullable but can be 0). It is a simple stored procedure which selects all fields from a database table. My requirement is that if the @IdParameter is greater than 0 then the Id field of database table is to be compared with @IdParameter else we don't need the comparison.

I tried using CASE etc but I am unable to solve my issue

I need something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE [Status] = 1 
  AND (CASE WHEN @Parameter > 0 THEN Id = @Parameter END)
```

Comment: Just to discuss the logic behind the condition: Your intended logic is `if A then verify B` or more simply, it matches the pattern `A implies B`. The  logical equivalent to that is `(not A) or B`, which is what both of the answers propose (with slight variations on how the `(not A)` is coded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE` returns a scalar value not a boolean result. You shouldn't, however, be using a `CASE` here at all but instead an `OR`. As, however, you also therefore have a "catch-all" or "kitchen sink" query, then you should also add `RECOMPILE` to your `OPTION` clause to stop you suffering (severe) parameter caching:

```sql
SELECT <explicit column list>
FROM dbo.TABLE_NAME 
WHERE [Status] = 1 
  AND (@Parameter = ID OR @Parameter IS NULL)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

I, personally, prefer to use `NULL` instead of an arbitrary value (like `0`) for the "catch-allness", which is what I've done above.

Answer (score 1):

If the @Parameter value is greater than 0, it checks (Id = @Parameter OR Id IS NULL), which includes rows where Id is equal to the @Parameter or NULL.

If the @Parameter value is not greater than 0, it checks Id IS NULL, which includes rows where Id is NULL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourStoredProcedure
    @Parameter INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE [Status] = 1
      AND (
            CASE
                WHEN @Parameter > 0 THEN (Id = @Parameter OR Id IS NULL)
                ELSE Id IS NOT NULL
            END
          )
END
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC Proc_Name
(
    @Parameter INT
)
AS
SELECT * 
FROM Table_Name 
WHERE Status = 'Active' 
  AND (ISNULL(@Parameter,0) <= 0 OR Id = @Parameter)
GO
```